# AmCharts how to move categoryAxis to bottom?

Tags: javascript, charts, amcharts

In AmChart I needed to display rotated values in X axis.

Do i do it by this way:

```
   "categoryField": "DATE",
                "categoryAxis": {
                    "gridPosition": "start",
                    "autoRotateAngle": 20,
                    //"gridPosition":"start",
                    //"minHorizontalGap": 20,
                    "minVerticalGap": 50,
                    //"autoWrap": true,
                    "position": "bottom",
                    "fontSize": 8,
                    "labelRotation": 320,
                    "axisAlpha":0,
                    "tickLength":0
                }
```

Problem is that labels are now in chart instead of the under the chart (See image below). So i would like to ask how can i do it?

In documentation of CategoryAxis I found nothing about positioning :
http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/CategoryAxis

Thanks for any advice.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Remove **"labelRotation": 320,** or set "labelRotation": 0,

If you have many record, You should set "labelRotation": 30 :D

Comment: Thanks, but I need to add margin top At least.